# How do I create a website template using html and css?

Tags: html, css

Maybe I'm not using the correct terminology because I can't seem to find an appropriate answer. I have built a header and a footer using html and css. This will not change from page to page and so I want to make it the template and simply change the content in between the header and the footer for each page of my website. I know I could simply copy and paste the code but if I wanted to change the header for some reason I would then have to change the header on each of my pages! Super inefficient. Coding is all about reuse. surely there's a way to do what I'm saying. Help me web developers!

Comment: you will have to use scripting language like php, asp.net

Comment: Either use something like handlebars for this, or use php's include().

Comment: There's so many possibilities here it makes the question overly broad and begging to get burdened by a multitude of opinions. You'll have to look at what your overall goals are, what platforms you wish to use, what kind of scaling you'll need in the future, etc. etc. etc. PS - Don't fall for the trap set by fan boys of one thing or another. PHP isn't the be all end all, nor is .net, there's lots of options beyond just them.

Comment: Like the first comment, I use a script on the server to populate HTML between the header and the footer. But if you don't or can't use a script on the server, then you can use an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do one of many things:

Use PHP files and `require()` the headers and footers in the main page, though you'll have to use a server on your localhost to test the pages.

You could maybe take a look into creating single page applications, using AJAX.
[AJAX Introduction here.](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp)

You could go a step further and pick one of the very popular JavaScript MVC frameworks.
[Read more about them here.](https://www.infoq.com/research/top-javascript-mvc-frameworks)

Finally, you could also do it the "old way" and use iframes, but that is honestly bad practice and will bring more harm than good.

Comment: I'm using Xampp to help me build the website so the php won't be a problem. PHP also seems to be the simplest solution.

Comment: Agreed.  I would add that if you haven't divined from the answers above whether or not there's a way to do this *only* using HTML and CSS the answer is more or less no.  By which I mean there are ways but most are pretty old-school and none are recommended.

Comment: To add to that, if you do decide to go for the PHP way, `include()` can be a safer way as it doesn't break the code if the called file fails, however if you wish to add no other PHP functions other than the ones used for templating, it really does not matter.

Comment: I found this very simple and short tutorial showing probably the easiest way of doing it using PHP. https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-to-include-php-headers-and-footers-on-html-site/ Thanks for everyone's help.